# Transfer Hard Disk space from one partition to another Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, hard-drive

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium. I have about half of my hard disk allocated to C Drive and now I want to either create a new partition or transfer a part of the C Drive space to other drives like D or E.
I cannot create more partitions as I have reached the upper bound for the same. If there is a way through this please do tell me.
If there isn't, please do tell me the if there is any transfer procedure.

Thanx in advance.

P.S.: I cannot afford to format my system or even take any risk with my data. I even can't afford to buy any softwares.

Comment: Artur, I didn't get your statement. Could you please tell me what you meant by this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shrink half the size volume C using Device Manager, then format freed unallocated space, but do not assign letter on it, but attach to any drive as a hard link to a folder on volume D or E. When you will write data to that folder on that volume, your data will be written to the disk C:. In other words you will be able to use an additional space on volume C without risky operations and this solution is ultra fast. In the future, be more patient when planning your hard drives configuration to boot windows on it. In linux or mac that is not a problem, since, them not using primary-logical partitions, but they can use GUID partitioning to reference to a particular hard drive partition.

Comment: Thanx Artur.I wanted to ask one thing before its implementation. If I ever format my C Drive, the attached space out of this also would get formatted? Basically, I want to ask whether the data is safe if I format C Drive any time in future?

Comment: @SandipAgarwal: It is safe to format C: because actual data is located on another physical hard drive, as i understand you well

Answer (score 1):

It is given for Vista but applicable for Windows 7 also. Just find the "Adminstrative Tools" from start menu by typing. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Thanx Tusar. I have already tried this as I have already mentioned. It doesn't work out as there is a restriction to the number of partitions allowed for Windows 7 HOME PREMIUM. I want to overcome that limit. Can you help me regarding that or some way to transfer space?

Comment: Windows does not allow to extend a partition. Got this tool on google. Its a free software not sure if it is suitable for you... http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/resize-partition-windows-7.htm